# Configuration virtual hosts

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, webserver, virtualhost

I try to configure virtual hosts. All I do step by step like [here](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_18.04&p=httpd&f=7)

My config:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2/sites-available# cat mmv.com.conf
    # create new for [mmv.com]
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.mmv.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@virtual.host
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mmv.com
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mmv.com.error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mmv.com.access.log combined
        LogLevel warn
    </VirtualHost>
```

My index.html in root folder

```
cat /var/www/mmv.com/index.html
    <html>
    <body>
    <div style="width: 100%; font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">
    Virtual Host Test Page
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       ubuntu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters


192.168.125.137 www.mmv.com
```

Looks like all I did right but if I try to open site www.mmv.com and I see default apache page.
Help me to find where I did mistake.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution! That right config:

```
VirtualHost 192.168.125.138:80>

        ServerName  www.mmv.com
        ServerAlias mmv.com *.mmv.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@mmv.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/www.mmv.com

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mmv.com.error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mmv.com.access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

And in file /etc/hosts have to be this:

```
192.168.125.138 mmv.com www.mmv.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/mmv.com.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
```

Then restart your apache server.

Comment: root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# ls -lah

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 Oct  9 19:25 mmv.com.conf -> ../sites-available/mmv.com.conf

It's done but does not work

Comment: For once, try your config without www. Thank you.

Comment: in the config I deleted www
and now site with www.mmv.com - apache default page
without "www" - I see the page "Welcome to MMV..." 
Without www site was changed but it's not my file index.html

Comment: Now try this in your config: ServerName mmv.com www.mmv.com

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I changed in config as you say but now does not works apache:
Oct 09 21:39:40 ubuntu apachectl[103052]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mmv.com.conf:
Oct 09 21:39:40 ubuntu apachectl[103052]: ServerName takes one argument, The hostname and port of the server
Oct 09 21:39:40 ubuntu apachectl[103052]: Action 'start' failed.

I think should be something one of these two.

Comment: Okey. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for trying))

Answer (score 0):

Stupid guess: the file is in sites-available, but was it enabled?
If you have debian you can use a2ensite mmv.com, otherwise you have to use ln -s as Kiani advised in ^^^.

Comment: root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# a2ensite mmv.com
Site mmv.com already enabled and this done but not work